# How can i create SASS mixins and use in every project

Tags: ruby, sass

I want to create a scss file with different mixins that I want to use in any project by simply using @import "mixinfile" and not to copy that file in every project. 
Similar to adding a folder to path in windows.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compass is Sass framework that not only provides a great deal of useful functions and mixins, but it allows you to easily create your own extensions.  If you bundle your extension as a gem (which I personally recommend doing), you won't have to remember where you put it on the filesystem.

http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/

When an extension is installed as a Ruby gem (which is easy to do, even if you don't know a thing about Ruby), all you need to do is add a line like this to your config.rb file:

```
require "extension-name"
```

And it will make all of your stylesheets from within your extension accessible just like you had a copy of them in your project directory:

```
@import "extension-name/widgets";
```

The author of Compass has a screencast of how to write your own extension here (doesn't cover creating a gem out of the extension):

http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/08/01/building-a-personal-framework/

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac, I would recommend you to use Codekit as a pre-compilator, it offer you the opportunity to import your own framework for every our your projects. Good stuff.

Look for @import Statements there http://incident57.com/codekit/help.php

Answer (score 0):

let's say the name of your mixin would be "example". So you would write "@import example" in your .scss files. In order for it to work, you'd have to have a file called "_example.scss" in your stylesheets path.

Now, you say you want to share this mixin across projects. For that you'll have to load your mixin through a lib, and if we're talking about rails, the best way is to do it using rails engines (see bourbon gem source code). Then add it as a dependency in your gemfile (you can use the git uri or other types of source).

Comment: Thank You but I know nothing about ruby. Could you be more specific?

Comment: what do you know about then? rails?

Comment: check https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/ source code, it's exactly what you'd like to do (sass mixin usable across projects), and they're using rails engines for it.

Comment: I did the gem install bourbon. Than i cd into the folder where i wish to install bourbon and bourbon install. It created a folder named bourbon within the current path (the path where i did the bourbon command). inside that newlly created folder i put a file named _mysass.scss. i tried @import "mysass.scss" and... error.What did i do wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Bourbon is like Compass in that it is a wrapper around Sass that gives you access to a bunch of prewritten mixins/functions.  Unlike Compass, Bourbon doesn't provide a way for you to create your own library to use on top of it.  You would have to copy the Bourbon project entirely and replace their stuff with yours.

Comment: @Bogdan, in which path are you creating your mixin? you should put it under BOURBON_PATH/app/assets/stylesheets for it to be imported to your project. But you best learn about engines and benefits: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html .

Comment: @cimmanon indeed, but bourbon gem is nothing more than a mixin (and a few helper methods), it seems to fit Bogdan's question (how to create a mixin and share it across more than one project). Either that or include the mixin in each project.