# gemfile for non-rails project?

Tags: sass, font-awesome, glyphicons

i want to use the font-awesome icons for a website.
it's a jekyll (ruby) project, so i thought about using the font-awesome-sass gem.

are gemfiles only for rails apps or am i missing something here?

the instructions for installation from the font-awesome website goes like this:

```
Add this line to your application's Gemfile:
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

And then execute:
$ bundle

Or install it yourself as:
$ gem install font-awesome-sass
```

i have the font-awesome-sass gem installed.

how do i proceed?

Comment: How do you normally compile your Sass files?

Comment: with 'compass watch' from the cli.
then... is it something i could put in the config.rb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gems are not limited to Rails.  Compass can use gems, but they need to follow certain conventions first.  I looked over Font Awesome and could not find any indication that it can be used by Compass.

Related:  [How can i create SASS mixins and use in every project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560295/how-can-i-create-sass-mixins-and-use-in-every-project)